# Generating XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows, xamarin, uwp

How can I create an XML file with custom tags and fill it with data (strings) from e.g. textboxes in C#?

To be more precise, I'm writing an app in Xamarin for VS 15 (windows.forms/UWP using PCL) and I need to save the data typed in textboxes, etc. in an XML file.

Example:

User types in his name in a textbox. Then types in his birthday date in another textbox. The xml file then should look something like this:

```
<userdata>
   <name>John Doe</name>
   <birthdate>15.05.1995</birthdate>
</userdata>
```

Comment: Make a class with properties and serialize to XML https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c

Comment: Translations: tag=element; custom=all elements are custom; data=text node (in the case of your example). You might want to use a standard date format for birthdate, though. At least then it'll be recognized as a date in an unambiguous format. See [XML Schema Instance (xsi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Types) types.

Comment: There are many existing questions (and answers) here related to writing XML from C#. Please do some research and make an answer to solve the problem yourself first before posting here. Once you've done so, if you run into difficulties you can explain the problem, include the *relevant portion* of your code here, and ask a specific question related to that code and we can try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I searched for over an hour before posting. There are a lot of similar questions but I didn't get any of the answers. I am quite new an inexperienced in programming.

Comment: You're going to have to get a book or follow a tutorial, you can't learn this stuff by trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an object for storing a "userdata" and populate it with the values from your text boxes.

Then you'll use the XmlSerializer to create the Xml of your object.

Something like this...

```
// Create a class to store your object
public class userdata
{
    public string name;
    public string birthdate;
}

// Instantiate and populate your person object
var userData = new userdata() { name = txtName.Text, birthdate = txtBirthday.Text };

// Set up your xml serializer based on your person object
using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\userData.xml"))
{
    var xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(userData.GetType());
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, userData);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sure the StringWriter was for debugging purposes. Please don't save the string to a ".xml" file; Save directly to a file so the charset declaration gets set to the character encoding that the writer uses to write the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll give it a try! What I don't get is if your code generates an xml file? If so, where is that file saved?

Comment: I updated the answer to save the Xml to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var xd =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement(
            "userdata",
            new XElement("name", TextBox1.Text),
            new XElement("birthdate", TextBox2.Text)));

xd.Save(@"filename.xml");
```